# Cannot Connect to Surry to get Php8

Tags: linux, php, linux-networking, apt, gnutls

My system is Debian Buster:

```
~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

I have run the following commands attempting to install Php 8.0

```
sudo apt -y install lsb-release apt-transport-https ca-certificates 
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y 
sudo reboot
sudo apt -y install lsb-release apt-transport-https ca-certificates 
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install php8.0
```

`apt update` then spits out the following error, which leads to php8.0 not being an existing package:

```
Resolving packages.sury.org (packages.sury.org)... 172.67.182.150, 104.21.18.148, 2606:4700:3030::ac43:b696, ...
Connecting to packages.sury.org (packages.sury.org)|172.67.182.150|:443... connected.
GnuTLS: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
GnuTLS: received alert [49]: Access was denied
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

I know this is not a networking issue because I can ping 'google.com' and 8.8.8.8 along with downloading packages from other third parties. I cannot seem to figure out how to get this work, I would be open to alternatives to Sury to get Php 8.0 installed. Is this my issue or an issue with Sury? Nevertheless, [Sury](https://packages.sury.org/) seems to be the best way to get Php 8.0.

Hopefully, someone way smarter than me knows why this is not working. If you have any further questions you can comment or private message me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your question and no reason why someone might downvote it. Indeed it should get an upvote or two. It's a good question and something very strange is going on there that should attract people to try to solve the problem.

Comment: So, the IP addresses for sury.org are CloudFlare addresses. If they were having a problem it would be international news, so I suspect that something is interfering with your connection. Is this server in China? Or is it behind a restrictive firewall or proxy that might be causing the problem?

Comment: I suspect it could be our AT&T firewall, it can be very aggressive and even go as far as to block Microsoft downloads. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the first command and the last command (nothing will be installed):

```
sudo apt -y install lsb-release apt-transport-https ca-certificates
```

and `sudo apt -y install php8.0`

The `-y` should be after `install`.

To install the required package, use:

```
sudo apt install -y lsb-release apt-transport-https ca-certificates
```

next:

```
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y php8.0
```